# How do i install phpredis on windows 8 using netbeans composer plugin

Tags: php, redis

I am including details of procedures i have followed along with my system and dependency details

xampp on windows 8

php 5.5

composer for windows

Netbeans IDE 8.0.1

**Procedures followed**

Installed redis on windows(already working as i have checked through redis CLI)

Installed composer on windows

Created new project under netbeans and added dependency using composer

Searched phpredis and installed this using composer under netbeans

under index.php included 'vendor/autoload.php' generated by composer

created object and selected methods from phpredis class(already provided by IDE)

Following is my code

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php'; 

        $objRedis = new Redis();
       $objRedis->connect('127.0.0.1',6379,3.5); 
        $objRedis->set('name','sam');
       echo $objRedis->get('name');

      ?>
```

**Now since all methods under phpredis are being provided by IDE, even then executing throws
    a fatal error: Redis class not found**